# Why can't I get DNS results for bing?

Tags: php, dns, bing

I have been trying to get DNS results for bing.com using php:

```
<?php
$domain = 'bing.com';
$dns_results = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_ALL);
?>
```

The problem is that I get a php warning: `Warning: dns_get_record() [function.dns-get-record]: Dns Query failed`

This code works fine with other domains. And `gethostbyname($domain)` works fine. So why is this failing? What's special about Bing's DNS? and is there a workaround beyond suppressing the error using `@dns_get_record`?

Comment: nameservers could potentially be down however it is working for me so that cant be the issue

Comment: That was the first thought that came to mind. I'm guessing bing has something special about it's DNS though.

Comment: how are you testing this? Locally or..?

Comment: @1337holiday Yes I'm testing locally on a windows 7 pc. Could that be the problem?

Comment: could be, DNS lookups usually happen over UDP and require a specific port to be open. Give it a try on a different computer and also check this out on how to set a "type" parameter http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Comment: @1337holiday thanks I'll check that out. Something else I just noticed the www sub-domain will return DNS results and the Type A records point to a134.dsw3.akamai.net I don't get it